# project performs actions all at once

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, thread-sleep

i am doing an android simon says app and i am in the light up loop,
for this example i have defined it so it would light up 4 colors because the array that has the numbers that light up the according numbers is 4 cells long

unfortunately it lights up all of the colors at the same time you could not distinguish the order i am trying to figure out why that is and how do imake it light up one color at once here's the code for my main activity and java calss that helps it

this is the activity:

```
package com.gabie212.simonsays;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private int i = 0;
    private Thread t = new Thread();
    private Button greenButton;
    private Button redButton;
    private Button blueButton;
    private Button yellowButton;
    private Button startButton;

    private ArrayList<Integer> randomColors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> userColors = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    private GameManger gm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        gm =  new GameManger(this);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        greenButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGreen);
        redButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRed);
        blueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBlue);
        yellowButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnYellow);
        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        greenButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        redButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        blueButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        yellowButton.setOnClickListener(this);





    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int num;
        for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
            num = gm.getColor(4);
            randomColors.add(num);
        }
        android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();
        //TODO if the start button is pressed multiple times simultaneously it starts the lightup loop multiple times simultaneously
        if (v.getId() == startButton.getId()) {

            for (i = 0; i < randomColors.size(); i++) //light up loop
            {
                switch (randomColors.get(i)) {
                    case 1:
                        greenButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.greenlightup);

                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                greenButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);
                            }
                        }, 2000);


                        break;
                    case 2:
                        redButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redlightup);
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                redButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red);
                            }
                        }, 2000);


                        break;
                    case 3:
                        blueButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bluelightup);
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                blueButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue);
                            }
                        }, 2000);


                        break;
                    case 4:
                        yellowButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellowlightup);
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                yellowButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow);
                            }
                        }, 2000);


                        break;
                }



            }
           /*
            for(i=0;i<randomColors.size();i++)
            {

                if(v.getId()==greenButton.getId())
                {
                    userColors.add(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    if(v.getId()==redButton.getId()){
                        userColors.add(2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(v.getId()==blueButton.getId())
                        {
                            userColors.add(3);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            userColors.add(4);
                        }
                    }


                }


            }

            for(i=0;i<randomColors.size();i++)
            {
                if(randomColors.get(i) != userColors.get(i))
                {

                    Intent i = new Intent( GameActivity.this, GameOverActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            }
            */


        }

    }
}
```

and this is the java class:

```
package com.gabie212.simonsays;

import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Created by Ronit on 21/02/2018.
 */

public class GameManger {

    private GameActivity gActivity;
    static Random rnd = new Random();


    public GameManger(GameActivity mA)
    {

        this.gActivity =mA;
    }

    public int getColor(int size)
    {

        return rnd.nextInt(4)+1;
    }
}
```

the part i had problems with is this part:

```
 int num;
        for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
            num = gm.getColor(4);
            randomColors.add(num);
        }
        android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();
        //TODO if the start button is pressed multiple times simultaneously it starts the lightup loop multiple times simultaneously
        if (v.getId() == startButton.getId()) {

            for (i = 0; i < randomColors.size(); i++) //light up loop
            {
                switch (randomColors.get(i)) {
                    case 1:
                        greenButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.greenlightup);

                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                greenButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);
                            }
                        }, 2000);


                        break;
                    case 2:
                        redButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redlightup);
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                redButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red);
                            }
                        }, 2000);


                        break;
                    case 3:
                        blueButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bluelightup);
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                blueButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue);
                            }
                        }, 2000);


                        break;
                    case 4:
                        yellowButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellowlightup);
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                yellowButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow);
                            }
                        }, 2000);


                        break;
                }
```

as i mentioned it lights up the 4 buttons at once instead of doing it in an order and i using functions such as sleep didn't work and the delay mills i used either didn't seem to work either, how do i make it light up the colors in an order (i think its using sleep functions but i am not sure).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are starting multiple coroutines all at once (inside the for loop). I guess you are not very familiar with the Runnable interface: everytime a runnable is run, it runs in parallel to your main process, which means that your code keeps going no matter what.

It runs

```
greenButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.greenlightup);
```

and sets a timer to run the delayed method. But while this method is waiting the for loop goes on, and

```
redButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redlightup);
```

is executed, and so forth. This is why your buttons are all colored at (almost) the same time. Your delayed methods all fire at (almost) the same time too!

Comment: not all of them light up at the same time , only those who's correlated numbers are in the arraylist, it was my teacher who said i should use this method instead of sleep which didn't work for me . how do i make it work one after the other?

Comment: should i split up handlers or something like that